# scenario validation rules showing null

Tags: php, validation, yii

model object is as

```
UserChangePassword Object
(
    [oldPassword] => 
    [password] => 
    [verifyPassword] => 
    [_errors:CModel:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [_validators:CModel:private] => 
    [_scenario:CModel:private] => change
    [_e:CComponent:private] => 
    [_m:CComponent:private] => 
)
```

model rules are

```
array('oldPassword, password, verifyPassword', 'required','on' => 'change'),
            array('oldPassword, password, verifyPassword', 'length', 'max'=>128, 'min' => 4,'on' => 'change','message' => Yii::t('recovery',"Incorrect password (minimal length 4 symbols).")),
            array('verifyPassword', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password','on' => 'change','message' => Yii::t('recovery',"Retype Password is incorrect.")),
            array('oldPassword', 'verifyOldPassword','on' => 'change'),
```

controller create model as

```
$passwordForm = new UserChangePassword('change');
$this->renderPartial('_password', array('form' => $passwordForm));
```

[image: Problem]

Please help me ?

[image]

Comment: do a var_dump($this->rules()); before the foreach loop - see what it returns. It should be an array. Or better, instead of var_dump, do die("<pre>".print_r($this->rules(), true)."</pre>"); - makes nice output

Comment: this error occurs when execution is on view file. and $this->rule is yii default functionality to assign validation rules to attribute, how i can print it?

Comment: @Jevgeni Bogatyrjov  another image added please have a look.

Comment: does `rules` return array or validation rules? or it just declate them?

Comment: @Ruslan Polutsygan  thanks i missed it while edit my model thanks.Please mention it as answer, so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rules` method has to return array of validation rules. Just like below:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        // validation rules go here
    );
}
```

if it doesn't (array is only declared and `return` keyword is missed) - this can cause the problem.